# Prove that $\small\sin x\sin y\sin(x-y) + \sin y \sin z \sin(y-z) + \sin z \sin x \sin(z-x) + \sin(x-y) \sin(y-z) \sin(z-x) = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\sin(x) \sin(y)\sin(x-y) + \sin(y) \sin(z) \sin(y-z) + \sin(z) \sin(x) \sin(z-x) + \sin(x-y) \sin(y-z) \sin(z-x) = 0 \;  .$$ I tried all identities I know but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Give us your attempt!

Comment: have you tried this: $\sin x = \dfrac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864895/easier-way-to-solve-this-problem-of-trigonometry

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use equalities for:

\begin{align}
\sin(x)\sin(y) & = \dfrac{1}{2}(\cos(x-y) - \cos(x+y)) \\
\cos(x)\sin(y) & = \dfrac{1}{2}(\sin(x+y) - \sin(x-y)) \\
\cos(x)\cos(y) & = \dfrac{1}{2}(\cos(x-y) + \cos(x+y))
\end{align}

> Then you'll get for the first term: $$\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(x - y) = \frac{1}{4}(-\sin(2x) + \sin(2x - 2y) + \sin(2y))$$